# Why my code doesnt works

Tags: php, sql

When im running the following code it executes! However, there's a problem. The `if($photoIDdislike["magic"] == 1)` doesnt work, why does the program say that the if-statement is false. What is my logical mistake and how may I fix it so that the code will work.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3306","root","root","photoshare");
$query = "SELECT ID,nickname,photoLikes FROM tbl_photo";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$query_dislike = "SELECT idGivenLike, nickname, magic  FROM tbl_check_like";
$resultDislike = mysqli_query($con,$query_dislike);
$photoIDdislike;
$photoID;
while($photoID = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result))
{
    if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDislike)!= null)
    {
        while($photoIDdislike = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDislike))
        {
                //checks if both of results
            if($photoID["ID"] == $photoIDdislike["idGivenLike"])        
                {
                if($photoIDdislike["magic"] == 1)
                {

                    echo '<a href=img/'.$photoID["ID"].'.php><img src="uploads/'.$photoID["ID"].'.jpg" alt="Picture" class="photo" width="800" height="600"/></a>
                        </br>
                        התמונה הועלתה על ידי '.$photoID["nickname"].'
                                <form action="unlike.php" method="POST" >
                                <input type="image" src="img/unlike.png" width="20" height="20"  name="submit" value="'.$photoID["ID"].'"/>
                                לייקים:'.$photoID["photoLikes"].'
                                </form>
                                ';

                }
                }   
        }
    }
    else
                echo '<a href=img/'.$photoID["ID"].'.php><img src="uploads/'.$photoID["ID"].'.jpg" alt="Picture" class="photo" width="800" height="600"/></a>
                                    </br>
                                    התמונה הועלתה על ידי '.$photoID["nickname"].'
                                            <form action="like.php" method="POST" >
                                            <input type="image" src="img/like.jpg" width="20" height="20"  name="submit" value="'.$photoID["ID"].'"/>
                                            לייקים:'.$photoID["photoLikes"].'
                                            </form>
                                            ';  



}
?>
```

My db structure:
tbl_check_like:
idGivenLink | nickname | magic(says if he gave like)

tbl_photo:
ID |nickname | photoName | photoLikes | photoLink | photoDeleteLink

Comment: This is impossible to answer, please post the structure of your database.

Comment: If the expression in the if is always returning false, you should debug your way to it to see why your magic variable isn't being set to one.

Comment: @matt3141 I've add my db structure (the all columns each db). ID - idGiveLink is the ID of the photo

Comment: @Renan but its should return true magic always when ive done the INSERT command changes the value of magic to one.

Comment: @Yoni It's pretty cute when people challenge reality because it doesn't match their desires. I've been trying to wish the sky into being green as well, but without success so far... *"but it should"* is the speech of the lazy. It is very clear and evident that it isn't behaving like you want it to. So go down there and debug the thing until you find out why that `**1**` isn't being set.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing this issue should not be too hard. `var_dump` the value of `$photoIDdislike["magic"]`. You will then need to take one of a few courses of action.

1. If the value differs from your expectation, e.g., it is equal to `0`, there was no issue in your application logic to begin with. Of course in this case, your equality check may need to be changed.
2. If the output corresponds with what you were expecting, check the data-type, i.e., that it is in fact a number.
3. If there is nothing printed, even after verifying that it is not an empty string by doing `echo 'var_dump:'; var_dump(...);`, the prior condition is never met, i.e., `$photoID["ID"] == $photoIDdislike["idGivenLike"]`.

The code for testing.

```
if($photoID["ID"] == $photoIDdislike["idGivenLike"]) {
    echo "var_dump:\n";
    var_dump($photoIDdislike["magic"]);
    if($photoIDdislike["magic"] == 1) {
        // ...  
    }
}
```